# Rails - rspec - How can I run all the integration tests, similar to rake spec:models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, integration-testing

The following commands work:

```
rake spec:models
rake spec:controllers
rake spec:requests
```

but the following does not:

```
rake spec:integration
rake spec:integrations
```

How can I run all the integration tests alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `rspec spec/integration/*` I guess.
I was hoping for an answer that worked with rake like the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, request specs *are* integration tests in rspec. Were some of the tests inherited from test::unit?

Test::Unit is the default test library for a new rails application created using the generator (unless -T is specified which skips the creation of test::unit files), so it will come with spec/integration, whereas for Rspec, the convention is to use spec/requests. In fact if you try to generate a new integration_test now by `rails g integration_test testname`, that will go into requests.

Comment: hmmm, that's interesting.  Let me check.

Comment: Well I checked and when I run `rake spec:requests` it only runs the request specs, not the integration specs.  Where could I look for a setting, parameter or some code that would tell me more about any test::unit connection?